# Seeking a more elegant solution to set buttons so they can increase specific ability level and stats

Tags: unity, performance, unity-ui

```
public class AbilitiesUpgradePanel : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] Button[] buttons = new Button[3];
    [SerializeField] Text[] abilityNameText = new Text[3];
    [SerializeField] Text[] abilityDescriptionText = new Text[3];
    [SerializeField] Text[] abilityLevelText = new Text[3];
    [SerializeField] Image[] abilityImage = new Image[3];

    private int totalAbilitiesCount = 3;

    public void RandomAbilitesToLevelUp()
    {
        List<int> generatedIds = new List<int>(); //I need each button to have unique ability
        for (int buttonIndex = 0; buttonIndex < totalAbilitiesCount; buttonIndex++) 
        {

            int abilityId = Random.Range(0, totalAbilitiesCount);
            while (generatedIds.Contains(abilityId))
            {
                abilityId = Random.Range(0, totalAbilitiesCount);
            }

            if (abilityId == 0) 
            {
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.AddListener(UpgradeBullet);
                abilityNameText[buttonIndex].text = Bullet.instance.abilityName;
                abilityLevelText[buttonIndex].text = Bullet.instance.abilityLevel.ToString();
                abilityDescriptionText[buttonIndex].text = Bullet.instance.abilityUpDescription;
                abilityImage[buttonIndex].sprite = Bullet.instance.abilitySprite;
            }
            else if (abilityId == 1) 
            {
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.AddListener(UpgradeLighting);
                abilityNameText[buttonIndex].text = Lightning.instance.abilityName;
                abilityLevelText[buttonIndex].text = Lightning.instance.abilityLevel.ToString();
                abilityDescriptionText[buttonIndex].text = Lightning.instance.abilityUpDescription;
                abilityImage[buttonIndex].sprite = Lightning.instance.abilitySprite;
            }
            else if (abilityId == 2)
            {
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
                buttons[buttonIndex].onClick.AddListener(UpgradeSatellite);
                abilityNameText[buttonIndex].text = Satellite.instance.abilityName;
                abilityLevelText[buttonIndex].text = Satellite.instance.abilityLevel.ToString();
                abilityDescriptionText[buttonIndex].text = Satellite.instance.abilityUpDescription;
                abilityImage[buttonIndex].sprite = Satellite.instance.abilitySprite;
            }

        generatedIds.Add(abilityId);
        }
    }


// Abilities (Bullet, Lightning, Satellite)
//BULLET
    public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Bullet instance;

    [SerializeField] GameObject bulletPrefab;

    public string abilityName = "Bullet";
    public string abilityUpDescription = "Default Projectile Shooting";
    public int abilityId = 0;
    public Sprite abilitySprite;

    private Enemy closestEnemy;
    private GameObject instantiatedBullet;

    public float damage = 15f;
    public float cooldown = .7f;
    public float castDistance = 18f;
    public float projectileSpeed = 4f;
    public int abilityLevel = 0;

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 moveDirection;

    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {       
       StartCoroutine(CastBullet());
    }


//SATELLITE
    public class Satellite : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Satellite instance;

    [SerializeField] GameObject satellitePrefab;
    [SerializeField] GameObject satellitesHolder;

    public string abilityName = "Satellite";
    public string abilityUpDescription = "Creates a sattelite flying around you";
    public int abilityId = 2;
    public Sprite abilitySprite;

    Vector3 center;

    public float damage = 20f;
    public float rotationSpeed = 100;
    public float distanceFromPlayer = 1;
    public int maxSatellites = 1;
    public int currentSatellites = 0;
    public int abilityLevel = 0;
    
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        satellitesHolder.SetActive(true);
        SpawnSatellites();
    }

//LIGHTNING
 public static Lightning instance;
    
    [SerializeField] GameObject lightningPrefab;

    public string abilityName = "Lightning";
    public string abilityUpDescription = "Creates a lightning strike";
    public int abilityId = 1;
    public Sprite abilitySprite;

    private GameObject instantiatedLightning;
    int instantiadetLightningsCount;

    public float castDistance = 7f;
    public float damage = 20f;
    public float cooldown = 1f;
    public int maxTargets = 2;
    public int abilityLevel = 0;


    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CastLightning());
    }
```

Comment: What specifically do you think is "bad" about this and what should answers focus on improving?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution is proper, maybe there is a way to set buttons differently, in a proper way, or this code is fine already, that's what I'm asking

Comment: Can you define "proper"? What is it about this code that feels "improper" to you? The more clearly you can articulate your concern, the better we can target answers to help with that aspect.

Comment: " if (abilityId == 0), 1, 2, etc." looks improper for me, I thought to create a class "Abilities" then each specific ability would inherit "Abilities" class so I could create "List<Abilities> allAbilities". This way I could make so "abilityNameText[buttonIndex].text = allAbilities[abilityId].abilityName". But I don't know how to add specific Listener to a button, and I'm not sure if this solution is any better than one above.

In the end, I want to create about 20+ different abilities, and this solution contains a lot of repeating code, that's why I'm not sure if it's proper.

Comment: Can you tell us what these instances are (Bullet, Lightning, Satellite)? It seems like they share many of the same properties -- can they derive from a base class so you don't need to refer to them by singleton?

Comment: Is there any difference between the code sections in each of those three if-statements? When they are all alike, then why not put them all in one `if (abilityId == 0 || abilityId == 1 abilityId == 2)`? [C# boolean OR-operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-or-operator-).

Comment: @AcmeNerdGames added examples of these instances, they can't derive from a base class. Yes, they share many of the same properties but they also share many unique properites.

Comment: @Philipp I'm adding specific listener to a button and referring to specific instance in every if statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> they can't derive from a base class. Yes, they share many of the same properties but they also share many unique properites. –
> xmaximix
> 1

Actually I think you can. This a pattern I use all the time for stuff like this and it works very well.

First, I suggest your abilities derive not from Monobehaviour, but from ScriptableObject. They won't recieve events, so you'll have to handle that some other way, (if at all -- do you actually ever need to instantiate an "ability"?*), but it does make for a nice neat way to create related entities that share many of the same properties and methods.

So -- base Ability class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Ability : ScriptableObject
{

    public enum Type
    {
        bullet,
        satellite,
        lightning
    }

    public Type type; // or use get; set; 

    public string abilityName = "Lightning";
    public string abilityUpDescription = "Creates a lightning strike";
    public int abilityId = 1;
    public int abilityLevel = 0;
    public Sprite abilitySprite;

    public virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Ability started");
    }

    public virtual void CreateAbilityButton(Button button)
    {
        // If button gameobject are configured identically can simply get child components using Find

        button.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();

        button.transform.Find("Ability Name").GetComponent<Text>().text = abilityName;
        button.transform.Find("Ability Level").GetComponent<Text>().text = abilityLevel.ToString();
        button.transform.Find("Ability Description").GetComponent<Text>().text = abilityUpDescription;
        button.transform.Find("Ability Sprite").GetComponent<Image>().sprite = abilitySprite;
    }

}
```

And a derived Bullet class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


[CreateAssetMenu (menuName = "Abilities/ Bullet")]
public class Bullet : Ability
{

    [SerializeField] GameObject bulletPrefab;

   // private Enemy closestEnemy;
    private GameObject instantiatedBullet;

    // extra properties for bullet
    public float damage = 15f;
    public float cooldown = .7f;
    public float castDistance = 18f;
    public float projectileSpeed = 4f;

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 moveDirection;

    public override void CreateAbilityButton(Button button)
    {
        base.CreateAbilityButton(button);
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => { DoSomeGreatAction(); });

    }

    public void DoSomeGreatAction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hello from Bullet");
    }


    public override void Start()
    {
       // do some initialization
    }
}
```

lightning...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Abilities/ Lightning")]
public class Lightning : Ability
{

    public static Lightning instance;

    [SerializeField] GameObject lightningPrefab;
    private GameObject instantiatedLightning;
    int instantiadetLightningsCount;

    public float castDistance = 7f;
    public float damage = 20f;
    public float cooldown = 1f;
    public int maxTargets = 2;


    public override void CreateAbilityButton(Button button)
    {
        base.CreateAbilityButton(button);
        button.onClick.AddListener(() => { DoSomeCoolLightningButtonAction(); });

    }

    public void DoSomeCoolLightningButtonAction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Lightning is lit, yo");
    }


    public override void Start()
    {
       // do whatever you want on start
    }
}
```

Etc.

And now the good part -- code to create the buttons is really simplified:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class AbilitiesUpgradePanel : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] Button[] buttons;


    [SerializeField] public List<Ability> abilities; // a list containing all your ability prototype


    private void Start()
    {
        RandomAbilitesToLevelUp();
    }

    public void RandomAbilitesToLevelUp()
    {

        List<Ability> threeUniqueAbilties = new List<Ability>();
        int buttonCount = 0;
        while (threeUniqueAbilties.Count < buttons.Length) // magic number
        {
            Ability proposed = abilities[Random.Range(0, abilities.Count)];
            if (!threeUniqueAbilties.Contains(proposed))
            {
                threeUniqueAbilties.Add(proposed);
                proposed.CreateAbilityButton(buttons[buttonCount]);
                buttonCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Making these scriptable objects means you can easily make many variants of each ability type -- each with whatever custom variables and methods you need to support that type.

[image: bullet ability scriptable object in inspector]

[image: test demo run]

*if you do need to instantiate an "ability" for some reason, you can create a sister runtime class, for which the scriptable object acts as an immutable.